# Json returned my HTML <br /> in unicode form \u003cbr /\u003e . Causing the <br /> printed as a text rather than making a new line

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, encoding, decoding

I'm using ASP.net MVC3 and i returned a model which is in Json format using Jquery.AJAX and then I pass it into a Jquery template to be printed out.

For example the Json that server returned is 
`{"Key":2,"Content":"I'm Jason\u003cbr /\u003ehow are you"}` 
instead of 
`{"Key":2,"Content":"I'm Jason <br /> how are you"}`

when I append it into an Div using Jquery template it printed out something like this:

`I'm Jason <br /> how are you`

while the intended result should be

```
I'm Jason 
how are you
```

Am I suppose to prevent the server from encoding the string in server side? But I think this may cause security issue.
Therefore I think I have to decode the Json string in client side but no luck so far. Can anyone show me an appropriate way to deal with this kind of problem? 
Thanks

*Updated
I tested with   `jQuery('#someDiv').append(data.Content);` and it print out as intended.
So the problem is probably related to Jquery template

I'm using this code to pass data into Jquery template `jQuery('#someTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo('#someDiv');`

My Jquery template

```
<script id="someTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
 <div>${Content}</div>
</script>
```

Comment: How do you process the JSON data?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue.  No need encode/decode or escape/unescape.

Instead of this:

```
${Content}
```

Use this:

```
{{html Content}}
```

The unicode with be displayed as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You should unescape your Content string, e.g.:

```
alert(unescape('\u003cbr /\u003e'));
```

Comment: No need to escape the unicode characters in json string, eg "The VAT for your purchase will be billed \u0020 within next 5 days", works fine. I have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with ajax templates. the string has a \n which gets ignored on the template and if I convert the \n to `<br/>` then the `<br />` is displayed instead of the linebreak.

if I use `{{ unscape(myString) }}` then the result is still 'some text `<br />` next line'

Comment: looks like there is a way to do this with jquery templates. http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-html/